# How do I update the value of a React prop in a Jest/Vitest test?

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, jestjs, vitest

Consider the following component:

```
function Timer({ gameStatus }: TimerProps): JSX.Element {
  useEffect(() => {
    let interval;
    if (gameStatus) {
      interval = setInterval(() => setTimer((num) => num + 1), 1000);
    } else {
      if (interval) clearInterval(interval);
    }
  }, [gameStatus]);

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  return <div role="timer">{convertToMMSSFormat(timer)}</div>;
}
```

I have successfully tested that the timer starts if the prop `gameStatus` is true using fake timers.

I'd also like to test if the timer stops once `gameStatus` becomes false:

```
it('stops counting when the game is over', () => {
let gameStatus = true;
const { getByRole } = render(<Timer gameStatus={gameStatus} />);
act(() => vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000));
gameStatus = false;
act(() => vi.advanceTimersByTime(2000));
const timer = getByRole('timer');
expect(timer).toHaveTextContent('00:02');
expect(timer).not.toHaveTextContent('00:04');
});

Error: expect(element).toHaveTextContent()
Expected element to have text content:
00:02
Received:
00:04
```

As you can see, manually setting `gameStatus = false` fails to actually stop the counter, but the code appears valid.

What is the reason for this behavior? What is a valid way to update a given prop in a test?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

The solution has been found:

```js
export function Timer({ gameStatus }: TimerProps): JSX.Element {
  useEffect(() => {
    if (gameStatus) {
      intervalID.current = setInterval(() => setTimer((num) => num + 1), 1000);
    } else {
      clearInterval(intervalID.current);
    }
    return () => clearInterval(intervalID.current);
  }, [gameStatus]);

  const [timer, setTimer] = useState(0);
  const intervalID = useRef<NodeJS.Timer>();
  return <div role="timer">{toMMSS(timer)}</div>;
}
```

I was rerendering a new `useEffect` with a new reference to `interval` on each update of `gameStatus`.

Using `useRef`, I created a fixed reference for rerenders.